# How to select last row from a series of linked rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

The problem that I'm trying to solve are HTTP redirects. Each time when user changes article's title a new URL is created, but old URLs should still point at the latest article.

It is possible to change article's title multiple times so the table that keeps track of name changes has a pair of old and new URLs.

Example:

```
orange -> pear
pear -> apple
apple -> grape
```

The table looks like this:

```
                   Table "public.redirects"
  Column  |           Type           |       Modifiers
----------+--------------------------+------------------------
 from_url | character varying(200)   | not null
 to_url   | character varying(200)   | not null
 code     | smallint                 | not null default 301
 added    | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "redirects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (from)
```

I'm dealing with infinite loops during insertions but the problem that I have is how to select the last URL to avoid issuing multiple redirects.

Using the example above if the request is for "orange" I want to issue a redirect straight to "grape". Is this possible to achieve in a single select query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [recursive query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) for this:

```
with recursive all_redirects as 
(
   select from_url, 
          to_url, 
          1 as level
   from redirects
   where from_url = 'orange'

   union all

   select c.from_url,
          c.to_url,
          p.level + 1
   from redirects c
     join all_redirects p on p.to_url = c.from_url
)
select to_url
from all_redirects
order by level desc
limit 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/358a7/1

The query would benefit from an index on `(from_url, to_url)`. If needed the query can deal with endless loops as well.

Comment: Thanks alot, that's exactly what I was looking for. After a second thought as a matter of prevention I decided to deal with endless loops, I managed that by adding `where c.to_url != "orange"` to the second select.